# Localization/Resource files in Class Library

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, web, localization

I am trying to achieve *globalization* in a `.NET` class library.  In a `.NET` web application this seems to work fine.  I can add multiple resource files under the `App_GlobalResources`.

e.g.

```
LocalizedText.resx
LocalizedText.fr.resx
```

However resource files are handled differently in Class Libraries.  I add a resource file by
1)  Opening the **Properties** for the Class Library
2)  Clicking on the **Resources** Tab
3)  Clicking on the link to create a **“default resources file”**

With this model it seems to only want to allow one default resources file.  I can rename files and seem to get around this **“one file”** limitation but if I produce resource files with the same names as above there appears to be no code generated for the **“LocalizedText.fr.resx”** file.  If I reference a string in code like so…

```
myControl.Text = Properties.LocalizedText.MyLocalizedText;
```

It references the **LocalizedText.resx** file for the value (*ignoring the fact that I have the culture set to French*).  I’m guessing that whatever auto-generates the code for the designer file sees that there is *already* a **“LocalizedText”** class and doesn’t generate the necessary code.

Is there not a way (equivalent to the web application project) that I can **use multiple resource files in a Class Library**, named differently for each culture, and be able to easily access this in code (trusting `.NET` to switch appropriately depending on the culture info)?

Many Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the edit sunbabaphu... much better!

Answer (score 1):

First: create a folder in your project named 'MyFolder'.

Second: add a resource file named 'MyResourceFile' to the folder.

Third: where you want access the resource values, import:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;
using MyProject.MyFolder.MyResourceFile;
```

and create a property that can access the your resource. Like this:

```
public static ResourceManager oResourceManager = new ResourceManager("MyProject.MyFolder.MyResourceFile", typeof(MyResourceFile).Assembly);
```

Fourth: Get the data from your property:

```
oResourceManager.GetString("ResourceKey", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```