# Localization in satellite library hosted in Blazor WASM

Tags: localization, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM app that references a library that uses resource files to provide translations.  The culture to use is specified explicitly by an option rather than using `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`, *et al.*.  I have a selector in the UI that allows the user to select the language to output, but I can't get the output from the library to use the specified language.

Example solution: https://github.com/gregsdennis/StackOverflow-BlazorLocalization

```
- MyLibrary
  - Resources/
    - MyLibrary.resx
    - MyLibrary.es.resx
    - MyLibrary.fr.resx
    - MyLibrary.it.resx
  - MyService.cs
- MyBlazorApp
  - Pages
    - Home.razor    <-- contains language selector and invokes MyService
```

It seems that the localized DLLs (created from the resource files) are copied to the output folder in their appropriate culture-code-named folders, but they're not available from Blazor.

I've only seen examples like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76795688/878701) where the goal is to add localization directly to the Blazor app, but that's not what I'm trying to do.

Other similar-but-not-quite-the-same questions:

- [Blazor WebAssembly cannot load resources files from class library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63225051/878701)
- [Localization/Resource files in Class Library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24812415/878701)